# How to jump to a specific debug point in the variable window of Netbeans

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, ide

Here is the case of my Netbeans debugging question:

I got a for loop from 1 to 1000 and i start netbeans debugging. I setup a watch on a value in the loop and i see the value is 1. After pressing the play button i see the value 2 and so on.

But now i don`t want to click 1000 times on the play button.
How can i instantly jump to a specific value like 500?

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up conditional breakpoints:

1. Create a breakpoint on the line you want to break.
2. Right click the break point and open break point properties
3. Check the enable condition checkbox and enter the condition:

   `if(count==500)` replacing count with the variable of your for loop
4. Run your program and it will only break when you hit 500.